# What are some effective strategies to pentest a native code library?

Tags: penetration-test, api, code-review, library

The vast majority of resources out there about penetration testing applications is about web and mobile applications; in some cases there are resources about so-called "native applications" which compile to machine code (such as C, C++, Rust, etc...). However, I've found *very few* resources about pentesting a **native code library**.

If I needed to pentest a C/C++ library (or portion of one) that is often used for "local"/utility functionality (not networking), it becomes a bit less clear on how this should be done, because potentially, a user application could or could not be passing attacker/user-controlled data to various library interface functions, and it's arguable whether or not the native library is even responsible for handling unintended inputs since the library documentation lists specific requirements for each API function that should probably be met in consumer applications.

For example, according to the *manpage* for the `malloc` function, it requires: `void *malloc(size_t size);` that a `size_t` is passed in as an argument for size. Therefore, it's no big surprise that if I were to instrument glibc and pass non-size_t data there, that will likely cause a malfunction, but doing so would also be misusing `malloc`. Likewise, the manpage *specifically states that the memory allocated by malloc is NOT initialized*. Thus, if a user application misuses malloc's return data, then that is the application's fault not the library.

Even still though, the fact is, untrusted data could make its way into the hands of native libraries. One strategy that I've seen some security researchers use is utilizing the "utility" or "example" programs provided with the library. For example, in the case of openjpeg, there are the [utilities](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/tree/master/src/bin/jp2) `opj_compress`, `opj_decompress`, `convert`, as drivers for their bug hunting. However, there are libraries where no such utilities are provided, and there are also problems with that methodology, such as poor test coverage and often, bugs are found in the driver itself rather than the library interface.